# Need help in array (calling an array)

Tags: arrays, html, canvas

Anyone can help me on the array part? I am making a color drag and drop game whereby the items will be dragged into a box and people will be notified when its wrong or right.

How do i call the array from:

```
 var items=[]
items.push({x:400,y:330,width:30,height:30,color:"rgba(100,223,0, 0.5)",isDragging:false});
items.push({x:300,y:330,width:30,height:30,color:"rgba(220,0,0, 0.5)",isDragging:false});
items.push({x:200,y:330,width:30,height:30,color:"rgba(220,223,0, 0.5)",isDragging:false});
```

to:

```
if (items[0].push(x > 400 && x <175 && y>50 &&y<235)){ 
 //console.log("ok");
 canvas2.innerHTML = "Score:" + 1;

 }

 else if(x > 255 && x < 376 && y > 50 && y <235){
  canvas2.innerHTML = "WRONG! please try again."
  rect = false;
  myMove = false;
 }
  else if(x > 455 && x < 576 && y > 50 && y <235){
  canvas2.innerHTML = "WRONG! please try again."
  rect = false;
  myMove = false;

 }
```

Comment: What is `if (items[0].push(x > 400 && x <175 && y>50 &&y<235))` supposed to be doing?

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: to get the positioning of the mouse up

Comment: Im trying to create a drag and drop game. I have 3 different color boxes where it can be dragged and dropped. And, they have to be dropped in the specific color area. When, its correctly dropped, the user will gain 1 point, otherwise, the text shown "WRONG! please try again."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will only push a boolean to the array:

```
if (items[0].push(x > 400 && x <175 && y>50 &&y<235)){ ...
```

It is evaluated first:

```
x > 400 && x <175 && y>50 && y < 235
```

Then the result of that (true or false) is pushed to your array (and nothing else). Your conditional check is basically checking the length which `push` returns which always will be non-zero so your condition is true and will always be used.

Your condition is also "impossible" as x cannot be higher than 400 and lower than 175 at the same time...

To fix this specific problem you need to change the code around a bit. I am not sure how you intend to use this as pushing the result to your array doesn't match with the content you already stored there and if you intended to store x and y as new objects you need to create a JSON string instead.

You could try this instead:

```
if (x > 175 && x < 400 && y > 50 && y < 235) {
    ...
} else if ...
```

(replace ... with actual code)

Comment: thanks for the explanation. But may I know how do I get the data items.push({x:400,y:330,width:30,height:30,color:"rgba(100,223,0, 0.5)",isDragging:false}); from  var items=[]
items.push({x:400,y:330,width:30,height:30,color:"rgba(100,223,0, 0.5)",isDragging:false});
items.push({x:300,y:330,width:30,height:30,color:"rgba(220,0,0, 0.5)",isDragging:false});
items.push({x:200,y:330,width:30,height:30,color:"rgba(220,223,0, 0.5)",isDragging:false}); to the if else statement?

Comment: @user2953775 Use an index: `items[0]` will give you the first item. `var item = items[0]; var x = item.x; //etc`. You probably want to use a loop to iterate over the items to check instead of fixed indexes though.